# Tuple unpacking: dummy variable vs index

Tags: coding-style, python

What is the usual/clearest way to write this in Python?

```
value, _ = func_returning_a_tuple()
```

or:

```
value = func_returning_a_tuple()[0]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`value = func_returning_a_tuple()[0]`  seems clearer and also can be generalized.

What if the function was returning a tuple with more than 2 values?
What if the program logic is interested in the 4th element of an umpteen tuple?
What if the size of the returned tuple varies?

None of these questions affects the subcript-based idiom, but do in the case of multi-assignement idiom.

Answer (score 10):

If you'd appreciate a handy way to do this in python3.x, check out the python enhancement proposal (PEP) 3132 on this [page of What's New](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/index.html) in Python:

Extended Iterable Unpacking. You can now write things like `a, b, *rest = some_sequence`. And even `*rest, a = stuff`. The rest object is always a (possibly empty) list; the right-hand side may be any iterable. Example:

`(a, *rest, b) = range(5)`

This sets `a` to `0`, `b` to `4`, and `rest` to `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 6):

For extracting a single item, indexing is a bit more idiomatic.  When you're extracting two or more items, unpacking becomes more idiomatic.  That's just empirical observation on my part; I don't know of any style guides recommending or mandating either choice!-)

Answer (score 3):

For list/generator comprehensions with key/value pairs I think the usage of the dummy variable can be quite neat, especially where the unpacked value needs to be used more than once (avoiding repeated indexing), e.g.:

```
l = [('a', 1.54), ('b', 4.34), ('c', 3.22), ('d', 6.43)]
s = [x * (1.0 - x) * (2.0 - x) for _, x in l]
```

versus:

```
s = [x[0] * (1.0 - x[0]) * (2.0 - x[0]) for x in l]
```

Another thing to note is that while unpacking and indexing are roughly as expensive as one another, extended unpacking seems to be an order of magnitude slower.

With Python 3.2 using %timeit in IPython:

**Regular unpacking:**

```
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> %timeit y, _ = x
10000000 loops, best of 3: 50 ns per loop

>>> %timeit y, _ = x
10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.4 ns per loop
```

**Extended unpacking:**

```
>>> x = (1, 2, 3)
>>> %timeit y, *_ = x
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 us per loop

>>> %timeit y = x[0]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 68.9 ns per loop
```